# Merge two values in if both values are same except blank in EXCEL

Tags: excel, merge, cells

I want to merge two cells in excel that have a value like this:

```
'a  b  c
 1  1  11
 1  2  12
 1     
 2
    1
 2  2  22
 '
```

I don't want to merge the number with a blank...
any help for that? I used concatenate function  but it cannot help me ...

Comment: Which formula did you try ? Update that one also

Comment: =CONCATENATE(B2, A2)

Comment: no it's just an example ..:S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce column C using an if statement and the "&" operator.
=IF(LEN(B2)<1,"",A2&B2)

If you want C to be blank in the case where A is blank, then you'll need an or statement also.

[image]

Comment: Nice approach (+1). `=IF(LEN(B2),A2&B2,"")` is a little more elegant.

Comment: I agree.  I tested Bathsheba's way, and it works too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data are orientated in columns A and B starting at row 1, `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1), ISBLANK(B1)),"",CONCATENATE(A1,B1))` is one way. Copy this downwards.

The returned value is a string type. A blank string is inserted into rows where either `a` or `b` are not given.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(VALUE(A1)=VALUE(B1),CONCATENATE(A1,B1),"")
```

OR

```
=IF(A1=B1,CONCATENATE(A1,B1),"")
```